# why is my header and footer styling different than my group members in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

My group and I are all sharing the same CSS styling page for our header and footer, and just copying the exact same code in our separate HTML code. But for whatever reason, my header and footer is different than everyone else's. We all tried but can't figure out why my page is the only one like that.

This what my header and footer HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="header">
        <div id="header_left">
          <a href="index.html">
            <img src="./images/ASA_logo.jpg" alt="ASA LOGO" width="80px" id="asa_logo">
          </a>
          <p>African <br> Student <br> Association</p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="e_board.html">E-Board</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li id="more"><a href="#">More</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="meetings.html">Meetings</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="fun_fact.html">Fun Fact</a></li>
                <li><a href="other_orgs.html">Other Multicultural Orgs</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="footer">
        <div id="footer_left">
            <p>Call us: 715-836-3367</p>
            <p>Email: <a id="email" href="mailto:chanc95@uwec.edu" target="_nl">chanc95@uwec.edu</a></p>
        </div>
    
        <div id="footer_right">
          <p>Follow us on:</p>
    
          <div id="footer_contact">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ASAEauClaire?mibextid=LQQJ4d " target="_blank">
              <img src="./images/facebook_icon.png" alt="Facebook Icon" width="30px" height="30px" id="facebook_logo">
            </a>
    
            <a href="https://instagram.com/uwec_asa?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y=" target="_blank" >
              <img src="./images/instagram_icon.png" alt="Instagram Icon" width="30px" height="30px" id="instagram_logo">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS for the header and footer:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .header, .footer {
    background: #8d5b4c;
  }
  
  .header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .header p, .footer p{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
  }
  
  #header_left {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  #header_left p, #header_left img {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #header_left p {
    padding-top: 17px;
  }
  
  #asa_logo {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  #asa_logo:hover {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  #nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  
  #nav > ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #nav > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:15px;
  }
  
  #nav > ul > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    visibility: collapse;
  }
  #more:hover > .dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
  
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px lightgray;
    border-radius: 5%;
    border-color: black 1px;
  }
  
  .dropdown li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  .dropdown li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  .dropdown li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  #footer_left{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #email {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #email:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  #footer_right {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  
  #footer_right p {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  #footer_contact a {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  #facebook_logo:hover, #instagram_logo:hover{
    padding: 1px;
  }
```

This is what my header and footer looks like:

[image]

And this is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

It's obviously very little issues. I've tried playing around with the padding and margins but nothing seems to work. And then changing things in the styling would affect my group members header and footer when there's is perfectly fine. Does anyone know why this is only happening to mine?

Comment: We can't say much about "what is the difference between these two things", when we only get the code shown for one of them. What I do notice though from your screenshots, is that the one project appears to be served over HTTP via a local web server, whereas the other appears to be loaded simply via the file system - _could_ make a difference. Does the browser console have anything to say?

Comment: If you right click on the page and select **"inspect"** you can use your browser inspector to see what CSS rules are being applied to which elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

hard to say with the code provided.

I did notice there are one too many closing divs `</div>` in the header which could be closing the header prematurely (just a guess). Please provide the other html